# How do you send close captions for Zoom.us meeting?

Tags: python-3.x, closed-captions, accessible

I've been trying to follow the instructions on Zoom's [website](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115002212983-Integrating-a-third-party-closed-captioning-service), but I'm getting a 400 error back each time I try to send the captions.

`{"timestamp":1594640701018,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"No message available","path":"/closedcaption"}`

The documentation says that a 400 comes back when the meeting hasn't started yet, but in my test scenario I have two devices connected to the meeting and I'm copying the Closed Caption API Token from the host before giving it to my test program. As far as I can tell, that's a started meeting, so there must be something else up. I've tried sending requests multiple times, but still get 400 errors back.

I'm using Python 3, and I've tried both `urllib.request` and `http.client`, but to no avail. What am I missing?

```py
    import urllib.request
    import http.client
    third_party_api_token = input('Third Party CC Token: ')
    domain = third_party_api_token.split('/')[2]
    if 'https://' in third_party_api_token:
        domain = domain + ':443'
    else:
        domain = domain + ':80'
    seq = 1
    while True:
        input('Press Enter to continue')
        
        formatted_url = '{}&lang=en-US&seq={}'.format(zoom_cc_url, seq)
        # formatted_text = 'Hello World\n'.encode('utf-8')
        formatted_text = 'Hello World\n'    
        headers = {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}
        print(domain)
        print(formatted_url)
        try:
            # r = urllib.request.Request(formatted_url, data=formatted_text, headers=headers, method='POST')
            # with urllib.request.urlopen(r) as response:
            #     print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
            
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(domain)
            conn.request("POST", formatted_url.replace(domain, ''), body=formatted_text, headers=headers)
            res = conn.getresponse()
            data = res.read()
            print(data.decode("utf-8"))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        seq += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Left an old variable name in the code, works fine when I remove it.
For reference, the below code works:

```
import urllib.request
import http.client
third_party_api_token = input('Third Party CC Token: ')
domain = third_party_api_token.split('/')[2]
if 'https://' in third_party_api_token:
    domain = domain + ':443'
else:
    domain = domain + ':80'
seq = 1
while True:
    input('Press Enter to continue')
    
    formatted_url = '{}&lang=en-US&seq={}'.format(third_party_api_token , seq)
    # formatted_text = 'Hello World\n'.encode('utf-8')
    formatted_text = 'Hello World\n'    
    headers = {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}
    print(domain)
    print(formatted_url)
    try:
        # r = urllib.request.Request(formatted_url, data=formatted_text, headers=headers, method='POST')
        # with urllib.request.urlopen(r) as response:
        #     print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(domain)
        conn.request("POST", formatted_url.replace(domain, ''), body=formatted_text, headers=headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    seq += 1
```